# Can I upload my React Native app to the App Store using an older Expo SDK?

Tags: java, react-native, sdk, expo, version

My React Native App has been built using Expo-SDK 40 on version 3.23.2. While troubleshooting why backgroundLocationAsync was not working, I found out that it's because of my SDK version. So I copied everything into a new project and have got it up and running, but it throws some errors. Those errors aside, the main question becomes:

Am I able to submit my app to the App Store using an older Expo SDK that may use different permissions? The p-list will still be the same, but the newer SDK has two separate requests for foreground and background location, while the older one just uses "requestLocationPermissionsAsync" Would that effect us?